# Как выводить все товары интернет магазина?

Tags: php, yii2

Создал CategoryController.php в папке controllers, вроде бы все писал норм, не могу выводить товары из бд, выводит ошибку "http ://site.loc/category/3"

Вот код в CategoryController.php

```
<?php


namespace app\controllers;
use app\models\Category;
use app\models\Product;
use Yii;


class CategoryController extends AppController
{
public function actionIndex(){
    $hits = Product::find()->where(['hit'=>'1'])->limit(4)->all();
    $this->setMeta('yiishoptest');
    return $this->render('index', compact('hits'));
}
public function actionView($id){
    $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
    $products = Product::find()->where(['category_id'=>$id])->all();
    $category = Category::findOne($id);
    $this->setMeta
    ('yiishoptest | . $category->name,
     $category->keywords, $category->description,');
    return $this->render('view', compact('products', 'category'));

  }
}
```

а вот код web.php в папке config

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'baseUrl' => '//site.loc',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'category/<id:\d+>'=> 'category/view',
            ],
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выводит и что это за зверь? `$this->setMeta`

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно с вызовом $this->setMeta, скорее всего так делать не нужно.
А в контроллере надо бы навести порядок. Если по канонам Yii2, а так есть смысл делать, то необходимо добавить метод получения модели, с проверкой на ее отсутствие.

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
    $model = Category::findOne($id);
    if (!$model) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }

    return $model;
}
```

А экшн я бы подчистил до такой степени, чтобы не городить всяких странных строчек кода. $id получать из запроса нет необходимости, он придет в виде аргумента.

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = Category::findModel($id);
    $products = $model->products;
    $this->setMeta
    ('yiishoptest | . $category->name,
     $category->keywords, $category->description,');

    return $this->render('view', compact('products', 'model'));
}
```

При этом в модели `Category` должна быть связь hasMany() типа такой

```
public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Products::class, ['category_id' => 'id']);
}
```

ТО, получив модель `Category`, мы легко получаем все products с помощью `$model->products`